# fetch request is giving successful response but the data doesn't get fetched

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a fetch request to localhost:8000/api/cars and when I logged the response.json() it was giving me 200 ok as response but the cars didn't get fetched when I tried to use the response in that syntax:

```
   function getRacers() {
    // GET request to `${SERVER}/api/cars`
  return fetch(`${SERVER}/api/cars`)
    .then(response => {
        // handle the response
        response.json()
    console.log(response.json)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // handle the error
        console.log(error)
    }); 
}
```

and then I called getRacers

```
getRacers()
        .then((racers) => {
            const html = renderRacerCars(racers)
            renderAt('#racers', html)
        })
```

and then I got the error after I tried to use racers in renderRacerCars():

function renderRacerCars(racers) {
if (!racers.length) {
return `<h4>Loading Racers...</4>`
}

I got error that racers is undefined and so we can't get its length, the error is:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> at renderRacerCars (index.js:176)
> at index.js:26

[image]

Comment: `return response.json()`

Comment: @ggorlen yes, that's it, thank you